# Secure connection between client and server application

Tags: security, ssl, client-server, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I know there are many question regarding this topic, but I swear I could not find the answer that best fits my problem.

It's a conceptual issue. I have a client and a server application and they must connect securely. I have been googling some options to achieve so but I'm not very satisfied to any of them.

1. The use of **asymmetric keys** requires the user to have a public key. This will be an opensource project so hardcoding the key in the source code is not an option. Also, I understood that using a certificate to trade the public key between both parts would avoid a *man in the middle*, but it makes me a little bit dizzy. I didn't understand very much how it can be accomplished and I don't know where I can get (for free) a valid certificate.
2. The use of **symmetric keys** requires both client and server to have the same key. So anyone who downloads the application would be able to access the cryptographer key and use it.

I've read somewhere I could generate a random number that varies from time to time and use it to encrypt data. However, since it is an opensouce application, anyone who is able to read how this number varies over time would also be able to decrypt data, right?

What am I missing here? I appreciate you help. Btw, I'm using Java and it's not a web application.

Comment: Are your users authenticated?

Comment: No, in fact that's the moment when the client sends the user's username and password.

Comment: In that case I would only trust certificates, the same way I would do if it were a web application

Comment: That you did not find an answer makes me no wonder. You were mixing up "asynchronous" with "asymmetric" (just corrected in your question). I am sorry to say, but this mistake clearly indicates that your security knowledge definitely does not meet the requirements. You should learn more about security, encryption and secure protocols. In the end it is better to use some existing secure protocol instead of inventing another insecure one.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but I'm facing a very particular situation in developing this program. I'm following @Bustikiller direction. Thank you for clarifying "asynchronous" and "asymmetric", shame on me.